# What is User Settings equivalent in standalone Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I have "user settings" file configured in m2e. I have local repository location configured in the file.

But how standalone Maven can know about it? How to configure standalone Maven to use the same user configuration and the same local repository location?

For example, the following command will add jar into local repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\kaptcha-2.3.jar -DgroupId=com.google.code
-DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion=2.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

there is no repository location here, so it will use someone it knows. Which one?

**UPDATE**

Can I setup user settings location not in command line, but in global settings?

May be I can edit `mavenrc_pre.bat` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local repository location is defined in `settings.xml`, which you can specify in command line using `--settings` option. This is how you define repo location: http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories

Answer (score 1):

Try `-s <path_to_settings.xml>` to set your settings.xml, local repository will be extract from it

Answer (score 1):

The default location for a user's `settings.xml` file is in the `.m2` directory under the user's home directory.